# Как восстановить непрерывную последовательность первичного ключа в MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

Первичным ключом в таблице является целое число с опцией auto_increment. Я удалил запись в таблице с id(первичным ключом) 4. Id следующей записи осталось 5, следующей 6 и т.д. Как перезаписать id каждой записи?

Comment: какой смысл вы в этом видите? кроме траты ресурсов...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Этого делать НЕЛЬЗЯ.

Назначение первичного ключа - однозначная идентификация записи таблицы. Причём на протяжении всего срока жизни таблицы. Именно таблицы, а не записи - т.е. даже если запись из неё удалена, значение ПК этой записи больше никогда не должно использоваться.

Хотите непрерывную нумерацию? заведите для этого отдельное поле и издевайтесь над ним как угодно, например:

```
-- создание поля
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD COLUMN numbering BIGINT NOT NULL;
-- инициализация начального значения (на 1 меньше)
SET @num := 0;
-- нумерация поля с требуемым порядком сортировки
UPDATE `table` SET numbering = (@num := @num + 1) ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Понятно, вторую и третью операции можно выполнять в любой момент, когда потребуется перенумерация, в т.ч. меняя требуемую сортировку (направление и/или поле).

А первичный ключ не трогайте.

Comment: Тогда есть как это реализовать? У меня есть ArrayList в котором должны быть те же самые записи, что и в таблице(но только одно поле). Но у меня id в ArrayList не соответствует id в таблице. Это мешает тем, что когда я хочу что-то удалить, я получаю id из ArrayList и передаю его в таблицу.

Comment: `когда я хочу что-то удалить, я получаю id из ArrayList и передаю его в таблицу.` Так передавайте не id, а value...